# Co-Signed an auto loan with my ex, help

Tags: auto-loan, co-sign

My boyfriend and I recently split up, but during the time of our relationship he helped me get a new car because his credit score is nearly perfect, and mine is terrible due to too many medical bills...

The car is technically in both of our names with him being the primary name on the loan.  Is there any way to get the loan transferred solely into my name?  Or will the lender say no and he needs to be on it because my credit is bad?  I pay everything on it, the only reason I needed his help was his credit score.

Comment: You can try to have the car refinanced.  It's not likely the current lender will just remove a debtor from the loan.

Comment: If your name is the sole name on the _title_, you own the car and can refinance into a loan without him.  If that isn't the case, you need to address that first.

Comment: If you were able to pay for all the loan payments, should've saved money for couple months and pay a big deposit.  Never use someone's credit rating like this.  The payment goes to **their** credit rating!